# How can I make an Excel cell with a DATE format accept dashes?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, date, cell-format

I have an Excel sheet in which various date columns exist. Initially, all dates were in format "01/01/2000" but I wanted dashes, so I did a find-replace all expecting all the slashes (/) to be replaced by dashes (-).

This change occurred in *some* cells and not to all cells. All my cells have the same format as per below.

[image: DateFormatAcrossAllCells]

Now, I have various dates in my sheet such as 01/01/2000 and 01-01-2000.

I need to change *all* dates so they resemble 01-01-2000. I have tried to change the slashes to dashes manually but Excel switches the date back to what it initially was, with slashes.

However, I have filters applied on my date column and I have noticed that in the filter, some dates appear as a year with a collapsible menu which then shows a month with a collapsible menu which then shows a day. Other dates do not show this and show the date in full, such as, "01/01/2000". Sample below.

[image: DateFilterMenu]

The dates that are displayed with collapsible items, can accept dashes (-) if I type them in, the dates that are not displayed as collapsible items, like "01/01/2000" *do not* accept dashes. This is my problem.

So how can I make those dates accept dashes and how can I make all my dates become collapsible in the filter?

Happy to make any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a bit of a fight with Excel but it turns out the steps to solving this craziness with the dates was for me to a bit more responsible ***before*** I started entering dates.

***Solution***

I wanted to have a date format for English (United Kingdom) but my Windows 10 format was set to English (US). So when I typed dd/mm/yyyy this was interpreted in Excel as mm/dd/yyyy. So I changed my settings.

**Control Panel --> Clock and Region** and on the **Formats** tab I chose the correct format, in this case, English (United Kingdom).

So I went back to my Excel sheet, removed all the dates from the date columns, changed the format for those columns to English (United Kingdom) and then re-added my dates.

Comment: I suspected it might be something like this.  Kudos for solving it, and thanks for posting your solution.  BTW, 2 days after posting the question, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a custom format (in your first image, the bottom left option).  This table shows the place holders for the different date elements:

[image]
*<sup>Courtesy [ablebits.com](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/)</sup>*

It isn't clear from the question whether your locale uses DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY format, so I'll just pick MMDDYYYY for an example.  You would enter in the custom format window: `mm-dd-yyyy` for formatting like `02-01-2019`.

Comment: Just tried it. Created a custom date like this "dd-mm-yyyy", applied it and it only changed certain fields and not all of them. The unchanged fields remain with slashes.

Comment: @NikosV, 1) Are you sure all of the fields (still) contain Excel dates and nothing has been converted to text?  2) If you manually did stuff to modify the cell content or appearance, that may be overriding the format you apply now.  You might need to clear all formats and then apply formatting.  Try setting one of the problem cells to General or Number and see what you get.  If it's a number like in the 43000 range, it is storing an Excel date.  You should be able to apply the custom formatting to that.

Comment: For number one, yes I'm sure all fields are DATE. For number 2, I just tried changing one field that keeps the slashes to a General format, the value changes to 36980 then I go and change that to a date like 01-01-2000 and when I press enter it automatically inserts slashes.

Comment: @NikosV, there's got to be more going on here than meets the eye.  The formatting just changes appearance.  There are no slashes or hyphens actually in the cells.  So if you were able to do find/replace, that means the contents were stored as text.  If number cells won't accept your custom format, there's something going on.  Let me see what I can find.  Can you shed any light on the source of the date data (manually entered, converted from source data in some format, etc.), the nature of the spreadsheet (has an Excel guru designed it), etc.?

Comment: Any form of protection applied to the problem cells?  If you click on a problem cell and look at it's format setting, what does it show for the format, locale, etc.?

Comment: Just did this actually. Here's what's happening. I go to a cell and change the format to a custom one, which is dd/mm/yyyy. I click OK and immediately after I right click on that same specific cell and Excel has automatically changed my format and set my locale to Armenian which is totally irrelevant. It keeps changing my locale whatever I do.

Comment: Sounds like at least a clue.  I'm about to shut down.  I'll check back when I'm up and running again.  If you haven't solved it and nobody else has come along with a brilliant solution, we can dig into it.